# How to install Mx libraries

Tags: shared-libraries, vala, clutter

I am trying Mx toolkit demo code on [this page](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/MxSample) but I get following error:

```
$ valac --pkg mx-1.0 mxgui.vala

mxgui.vala:4.7-4.8: error: The namespace name `Mx' could not be found
using Mx;
      ^^
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

I have following `clutter` packages installed on my Debian Stable Linux system:

```
$ apt search clutter | grep installed

gir1.2-clutter-1.0/stable,now 1.26.4+dfsg-2 amd64 [installed]
gir1.2-cogl-1.0/stable,now 1.22.8-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gir1.2-coglpango-1.0/stable,now 1.22.8-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0/stable,now 1.8.4-4 amd64 [installed]
libclutter-1.0-0/stable,now 1.26.4+dfsg-2 amd64 [installed]
libclutter-1.0-common/stable,stable,now 1.26.4+dfsg-2 all [installed,automatic]
libclutter-1.0-dev/stable,now 1.26.4+dfsg-2 amd64 [installed]
libclutter-gtk-1.0-0/stable,now 1.8.4-4 amd64 [installed]
libclutter-gtk-1.0-dev/stable,now 1.8.4-4 amd64 [installed]
libxkbcommon-dev/stable,now 1.0.3-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libxkbcommon0/stable,now 1.0.3-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mx is not developed any more, and Clutter [has been archived](https://blogs.gnome.org/clutter/2022/02/16/retiring-clutter/) in early 2022 after being in deep maintenance mode since 2016.

You should not use Mx or Clutter in newly written code. The recommendation is to use GTK4.

Answer (score 2):

If it's not finding the namespace then the VAPI file for the library is not being found, it's probably not installed.

The MX Toolkit library can generate a VAPI,  [read this commit](https://github.com/clutter-project/mx/commit/f7587474f12d89ad3a9830d726d787b71af497f9). It may be your distribution doesn't package it or you need to install the relevant package.

Comment: Good information but how do I proceed to solve my problem? It will be great if you can put specific steps in your answer.

Comment: It seems that libmx is no longer packaged in Ubuntu / Debian / Arch Linux and probably others. Is there even active development? The Git repo at https://github.com/clutter-project/mx has commits 9 years ago!